# Access Liferay Web services using JSON API

Tags: web-services, liferay, portal, liferay-6

Hi i created a plugin portlet. In the JSP i am accessing all countries list by using JSON API. It is working fine for Logged in users. But for the Guest users i am unable to access the web service. I am working on Liferay 6.0.6. The following is my code.

```
Liferay.Service.Portal.Country.getCountries(
            {}, 
            function(result) {
                for(var count=0;count< result.length;count++){
                    alert(result[count].name);
                    var option = document.createElement("option");

                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Liferay 6.1, you can achieve it by adding a property to portal-ext.properties file

```
json.service.public.methods=getCountries
```

If you need to check the whole flow checkout

```
JSONServiceAction
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the serviceContext with permissions to the Service.

Can you try by setting the communityPermissions and guestPermissions as VIEW ?

```
Liferay.Service.Portal.Country.getCountries(
        {

        serviceContext: jQuery.toJSON(
            {
                communityPermissions: communityPermission,
                guestPermissions: guestPermission,
                scopeGroupId: themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()
            }
        )

        }, 
        function(result) {
            for(var count=0;count< result.length;count++){
                alert(result[count].name);
                var option = document.createElement("option");

            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: I am getting a javascript error i.e "Object doesn't support property or method 'request' at the followng line 'AUI().io.request(serviceUrl,config);'

Comment: Below is the syntax. Make sure the syntax is right..

For more details you can visit this link.

 
www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/json+service+api



Liferay.Service.NAMESPACE.ENTITY.METHOD(
        {
            PARAMETER_1: VALUE_1,
            PARAMETER_2: VALUE_2
        },
        function(message) {
            var exception = message.exception;

            if (!exception) {
                // Process Success
            }
            else {
                // Process Exception
            }
        }

Comment: Hi Sharana, I have gone through that article.I am getting problem because of unavailablity of AUI().io.request() method for the guest user. Thanks for giving reply.

Comment: ok, may be the service you are trying to access needs to be authenticated I think. try n set this 

json.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1

in your portal-ext proeprties if you are using localhost? or the server IP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for the above problem. I am unable to access JSON API because Liferay is using A.io.request for AJAX Calls which is available for Logged in Users only. So I have prepared the following code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: '<%=themeDisplay.getURLPortal() %>'+'/tunnel-web/json?serviceClassName=com.liferay.portal.service.CountryServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=getCountries',

                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(countriesList) {
                        alert(countriesList);
                        alert(countriesList[0].countryId);
                        }

                    }       
            });
```